# How can I add a value to $scope from the template?

Tags: angularjs

Okay, I know this is a bit of a hack. I'm building a Facebook-application using angular. When in a tab, Facebook posts some info that you get to access server-side. For example if the user has liked the page. You can access this data server side. I would like to add it to the scope somehow. Using regular javascript, I would do this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php
            if($signed_request['page']['liked'] == 1){
                echo 'var liking = true';
            }else{
                echo 'var liking = false';
            }
        ?>
    </script>
```

in my index.php-file.

I need the data in the scope because I need a button to be disabled if you havent liked the page:

```
<input class="mybtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="VALIDEZ VOTRE CANDIDATURE" ng-disabled="!liking">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

1. Your js

   ```
       <?php
           if($signed_request['page']['liked'] == 1){
               echo 'var liking = true';
           }else{
               echo 'var liking = false';
           }
       ?>
   ```

In the app or template

```
<section ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   {{liking}}
</section>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.liking = $window.liking;
}]);
```

Comment: I didn't know about $window, that is great!